# How to I update the path to a moved git-svn remote branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I have been using git and git-svn for a while now but we have moved out svn repository server to another location. So what i am wondering is what to I need to do for git to look at the new remote path so i can continue like before. I have tried changing the url in config to look at the new repo but then when i try git svn rebase I just get :

`Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`

The svn repo is exactly the same but has just moved locations to another url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `svn-remote.svn.url`. You can view it like so

```
% git config --get svn-remote.svn.url
```

and set it like this:

```
% git config svn-remote.svn.url http://foo/bar
```

or via your editor:

```
% git config -e
```

Comment: This worked for setting the url however when i try to rebase the branches from the svn master branch it wants to do a full fast forward on all commits ;(.